# Read children from Firebase using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Database:
[image]

Hey guys, so i need to use FirebaseListAdapter with the above database structure, is there any way to read the children (address/date), is it even possible or do i have to change the structure

Comment: which data on the structure you want to show on you `ListView`?

Comment: Whether this is possible depends on what you want to show and how you want to show it. Where are you having problems? Can you share the [minimal, complete code of where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i want to show the values of date and address